# How to add a subreport in a new window?

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I am developing a SSRS 2008 R2 RDL with a chart.  Currently, I have a subreport built into this chart where if they click on a pie piece it goes directly to this subreport.  It is currently configured as an action on the series via "Go to Report".

However, my customer wants it to instead open a new browser window so that they can still see original chart without having to rerun my report.  Also, this subreport requires several input parameters.  I tried the "Go to URL" Action link instead and entered the URL there.  But this didn't work cause I couldn't pass in my input parameters.  How can I do this?

This subreport takes multiple parameters.  I have it configured as:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://evolvdb/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fIncoming%2fCensus_by_Date_Range2_Subreport&rs:Command=Render&startdate="+Parameters!startdate.Value+"&enddate="+Parameters!enddate.Value+"&region="+Parameters!region.Value+"&state="+Parameters!state.Value+"&office="+Parameters!office.Value+"&status="+Parameters!status.Value+"&program_hyperlink="+Fields!program_code.Value+"&funding_source_param="+Parameters!funding_source.Value+"'))"
```

But when I try to click this subreport it is not clickable.

I also tried this, but this exceeds the 255 character count:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://evolvdb/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fIncoming%2fCensus_by_Date_Range2_Subreport&rs:Command=Render&startdate=" & Parameters!startdate.Value & "&enddate=" & Parameters!enddate.Value & "&region=" & Parameters!region.Value & "&state=" & Parameters!state.Value & "&office=" & Parameters!office.Value & "&status=" & Parameters!status.Value & "&program_hyperlink=" & Fields!program_code.Value & "&funding_source_param=" & Parameters!funding_source.Value & "'))"
```

I also tried this, but this was not clickable either:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://evolvdb/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fIncoming%2fCensus_by_Date_Range2_Subreport&rs:Command=Render
&startdate="+Parameters!startdate.Value+"
&enddate="+Parameters!enddate.Value+"
&region="+Parameters!region.Value+"
&state="+Parameters!state.Value+"
&office="+Parameters!office.Value+"
&status="+Parameters!status.Value+"
&program_hyperlink="+Fields!program_code.Value+"
&funding_source_param="+Parameters!funding_source.Value+"'))"
```

Comment: Hi, are any of the parameters multi-valued? Then the url would look different.

Comment: No, none of the parameters are multivalued.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at the last code snippet that you tried and here is my feedback:

- The report path doesn't look correct. Should be in the format `http://evolvdb/ReportServer/Path/To/Report&Parameters=XX`
- You can't concatenate strings in SSRS with `+` and need to use `&` instead.

Example:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://evolvdb/ReportServer/Incoming%2fCensus_by_Date_Range2_Subreport&rs:Command=Render
&startdate=" & Parameters!startdate.Value & "
&enddate=" & Parameters!enddate.Value & "
&region=" & Parameters!region.Value & "
&state=" & Parameters!state.Value & "
&office=" & Parameters!office.Value & "
&status=" & Parameters!status.Value & "
&program_hyperlink=" & Fields!program_code.Value & "
&funding_source_param=" & Parameters!funding_source.Value & "'))"
```

My general advice for creating SSRS links is to take your browser and start there with zero programming.  Ensure that your report path is correct, then manually add a parameter and ensure the report accepts the parameter value correctly. Once you have a working URL example, create a textbox in your report that spits out the URL string you are trying create.  This is an easy way to ensure you are getting the expected output and you can compare to the URL that you manually crafted in the first step. Lastly, put the finished expression into the "Go to URL" action and you should most likely have a link that works as expected.